# How to change color one button in many button Vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I want to change the color of only 1 button selected among 5 buttons.

```
<button
      class="hover:bg-brand-blue  hover:text-white focus:bg-brand-blue focus:text-white"
      @click="say(item.message)"
    >
      <span class="text-sm ">{{ item.message }}</span>
 </button>
```

in data

```
data() {
return {
  reason: '',
  items: [
    { message: '1' },
    { message: '2' },
    { message: '3' },
    { message: '4' },
    { message: '5' }
  ]
};
```

},

in js

```
methods: {
say: function(message) {
  this.reason = message;
},
```

When I choose a color and change, but When me put text in textarea, the selected button color disappears.
I use css tailwind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using class bindings: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      reason: '',
      items: [
        { message: '1' },
        { message: '2' },
        { message: '3' },
        { message: '4' },
        { message: '5' }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    say: function(message) {
      this.reason = message;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.3/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button
    v-for="item in items"
    :key="item.message"
    class="bg-blue-400 hover:bg-blue-500 px-6 py-2 rounded border m-2"
    :class="{
      'bg-blue-900': item.message === reason
    }"
    @click="say(item.message)"
  >
    <span class="text-sm ">{{ item.message }}</span>
 </button>
</div>
```